# Pycharm is no more identifying my existing django project and opening as django project

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I did git pull to take new changes from remote to my local django project. After doing that when I click on manage.py to open my django project. It is not opening it as django project as it used to do before.
[image]

It can be seen from the black marked area as it is not showing my apps and when i try to edit other files in my apps it gives me dialog box saying this.
[image]

It is so annoying can anyone tell me hwo to fix my pycharm???

Comment: It seems the project settings got corrupted, try to close PyCharm, backup `.idea/` in the project root, remove `.idea/` in the project root, reopen the project.

Comment: note: the .idea directory may not be stored in the repository (for good reasons, see next point), or it may have settings of an other users, so breaking your environment.

Comment: so should I just remove the whole .idea folder or just the files inside that folder and then reopen the project through pycharm -> open project? P.S:- i am using pycharm edu version. Also, do I need to run some commands to ceate the .idea folder or it will get created automatically once i reopen?